# Embed Twitter Percent-encoding

Tags: twitter, urlencode

I was trying to copy the same method to my website by using the below code, but when I implement other twitter user or account, it is not working. Can anyone check if the code format is still working in other Twiiter account?

```
<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 height=250 width=550 src="https://twitframe.com/show?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Fjack%2Fstatus%2F20"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle and looks like the code is working fine! Tested with two other users and both are loading fine. You have to check if your URL is properly encoded and if you have any adblockers that blocks social media features.

[image: Sample code output]

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/ftcz6pdu/4/

Sample code:

```
<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 height=250 width=550 src="https://twitframe.com/show?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FItsSkyLOL%2Fstatus%2F1011166507257270273"></iframe>

<iframe border=0 frameborder=0 height=250 width=550 src="https://twitframe.com/show?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2FPoppyHarlowCNN%2Fstatus%2F1010899818955333632"></iframe>
```

The online URL encoder that I used: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: Could it possible add timeline tweets (profile tweets)?

Comment: Yeah Twitter has an [official tool](https://publish.twitter.com/#) which allows you to embed profile, hashtags, list, collection, likets etc... And you can choose the display format.